# Do a notification with a timepicker

Tags: android

I need to make a notification at the time that is selected in the timepicker, and have it repeated from time to time.
this is my code (im a begginer on android and i don't hava any idea)

If   could be explained as much as possible, in order to understand better

```
public class paciente extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText med;
private int horas;
private int minutos;
private TimePicker timePicker1;
private Button botonEjemplo;
private AlarmManager alarmaManager;
private PendingIntent alarmaIntent;
Button btnDatePicker, btnTimePicker;
EditText txtTime, medicamento, dosis, proxima_toa, hora;
private int mYear, mMonth, mDay, mHour, mMinute;
/**
 * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
 * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
 */
private GoogleApiClient client;

@SuppressLint("WrongViewCast")
@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_paciente);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    medicamento = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    dosis = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);
    hora = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText7);


    btnTimePicker = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button21);
    txtTime = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText6);

    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
}


public void algo(View v) {


    if (v == btnTimePicker) {

        // Get Current Time
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        // Launch Time Picker Dialog
        TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this,
                new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay,
                                          int minute) {

                        txtTime.setText(hourOfDay + ":" + minute);

                    }
                }, mHour, mMinute, false);
        timePickerDialog.show();

    }


}


public void aceptar(View view) {
    ConexionBD C1 = new ConexionBD(this);
    C1.abrirConexion_Medicamentos();
    String m, d, t, h;
    m = this.medicamento.getText().toString();
    d = this.dosis.getText().toString();
    t = this.txtTime.getText().toString();
    h = this.hora.getText().toString();
    C1.agregar_med(m, d, t, h);


}
```

}